# Plotting a stacked dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, stacked-chart

I would like to use the pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar(stacked=True) functionality to visualise my dataframe (see below head).

Selecting 1 period, I would like the "num" for each "Wave" to be stacked across "Electrodes". Ideally, each period would be plotted in a separate subplot. Current code:

```
one = df[df["Period"]=="1"]
one.plot.bar(stacked=True);
plt.show()
```

[image: current datafram]

In the example below, this would mean a,b,c,d represent the different Waves and 0-9 represent the different electrodes.

[image: stacked plot example]

I think it's a matter of re-ordering my dataframe to the expectations of plot.bar, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's the first 30 rows of the DataFrame

```
    Electrode   Period  Wave    num
0   7   10  Beta    1
1   8   12  Beta    1
2   15  10  High gamma  1
3   4   10  Theta   1
4   11  4   High gamma  1
5   12  13  High gamma  3
6   11  4   Delta   3
7   11  4   Theta   0
8   14  0   Delta   2
9   14  1   Beta    0
10  11  6   Low gamma   1
11  1   9   Theta   0
12  8   1   Theta   0
13  5   8   Theta   0
14  10  0   Low gamma   2
15  13  12  Alpha   1
16  8   13  Alpha   1
17  10  0   Beta    1
18  7   5   Alpha   2
19  10  3   Theta   0
20  14  6   High gamma  2
21  4   11  Beta    1
22  4   5   Delta   1
23  4   10  High gamma  2
24  10  0   High gamma  3
25  12  4   Alpha   1
26  8   8   Theta   0
27  8   11  Beta    1
28  6   2   Delta   2
29  12  7   Low gamma   3
```

Comment: I am working on second part of question, is number of period known before?

Comment: it changes across groups, but we can assume say 6 periods

Comment: OK, so please test my solution and if some problem, get me know. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `mean` with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
one = df[df["Period"]==10].groupby(['Electrode','Wave'])['num'].mean().unstack()
one.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

For all subplots:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Period')
nrows = int(math.ceil(len(grouped)/2.))
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows,2, figsize=(12,30))

for (name, df), ax in zip(grouped, axs.flat):
    df.groupby(['Electrode','Wave'])['num'].mean().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

Comment: I recieved this error : "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". My "df.index" yields "RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1344, step=1)"

Answer (score 0):

Following the error inspired by jezrael, I found this solution :

```
df[df["Period"]=="1"].pivot_table(values="num", index=["Electrode"], columns="Wave", aggfunc='mean').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```